# Minima values of nested array (possibly partially empty)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'll like to compute the minimums of some nested 2D arrays on axis 1.
My problem is the following: The arrays might have 1 (or more) empty axis, which if I try to apply `np.min` on it will throw some errors.

Note that I'll like the code to return `-1` if the axis is empty (By initialisation my array can't have negative values).
For example, I might want to have the minima values of `m` defined as follow:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([np.array([1,2]),np.array([3,4,5,6]),np.array([]),np.array([7,8,9])])
# Expected output in this case: [1,3,-1,7]
```

I first try:

```
_min = np.min(m, axis=1)
```

Which gives the following error:

> ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds

So, since the error comes from the fact that the array in nested (it has shape `(4,)`, I tried:

```
_min = [np.min(x) for x in m]
```

Which throw:

> ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity

Here the error comes from the fact that `m[2] = []` which is zero-size array.

All I come up with is this inefficient and ugly solution:

```
_min = []
for x in m:
    if len(x) > 0:
        _min.append(np.min(x))
    else:
        _min.append(-1)
# [1, 3, -1, 7]
```

Is there a simple way to achieve that with a more pythonic way?

---

**edit**
The pythonic solution proposed by @Divakar doesn't work when the empty axis is the last element (`m[-1]`):

```
m = np.array([np.array([0.53, 0.56]), np.array([0.33, 0.31, 0.27, 0.48, 0.36, 0.35, 0.27, 0.24]), np.array([])])
```

Error given:

> IndexError: index 10 out-of-bounds in minimum.reduceat [0, 10)

Comment: This is not a nested `np.array`, but an array of `list`. NumPy 1.13 is more explicit about this, showing your `m` array as `array([list([1, 2]), list([3, 4, 5, 6]), list([]), list([7, 8, 9])], dtype=object)`

Comment: @Eric I have the same errors when I defined explicitely as np.array-s. E.g.: `m = np.array([np.array([0.53, 0.56]), np.array([0.33, 0.31, 0.27, 0.48, 0.36, 0.35, 0.27, 0.24]), np.array([])])`

Comment: Indeed, but it's still worth realizing that those things are not the same

Comment: @Eric My mistake, in my code it is generated as nested np.array, I forget to add it when I wrote my small example. I edited the question to fix it. Thank you for noticing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Vanilla Python**

One approach would be -

```
[min(i) if len(i)>0 else -1 for i in m]
```

Sample run -

```
In [270]: m = np.array([[1,2],[3,4,5,6],[],[7,8,9]])

In [271]: [min(i) if len(i)>0 else -1 for i in m]
Out[271]: [1, 3, -1, 7]
```

We can skip listing the `len` there as suggested by [@blacksite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779475/compute-minima-values-of-nested-array/44779521#comment76539520_44779521) -

```
In [307]: [min(i) if i else -1 for i in m]
Out[307]: [1, 3, -1, 7]
```

**Bit more NumPythonic approach**

With NumPy, we can flatten out the input array to a regular one and then use `np.minimum.reduceat` to perform min finding in intervals, like so -

```
def min_per_elem(m):
    a = np.concatenate(m)
    l = np.array([len(i) for i in m])
    split_idx = np.unique(np.r_[0,l.cumsum()])[:-1]
    out = np.full(len(l),-1,dtype=a.dtype)
    out[l>0] = np.minimum.reduceat(a, split_idx)
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [74]: m
Out[74]: 
array([array([], dtype=float64), array([ 0.53,  0.56]),
       array([], dtype=float64),
       array([ 0.33,  0.31,  0.27,  0.48,  0.36,  0.35,  0.27,  0.24]),
       array([], dtype=float64)], dtype=object)

In [75]: min_per_elem(m)
Out[75]: array([-1.  ,  0.53, -1.  ,  0.24, -1.  ])
```

Comment: You could even do `[min(i) if i else -1 for i in m]`, i.e. taking out the `len` test.

Comment: @blacksite Thanks!  Didn't know that. Edited.

Comment: Thanks Divakar! The Pythonic approach is what I was looking for. I also need to compute max and mean of  `m`, `np.maximum.reduceat` works well but I can't find an equivalent for the average... Any ideas?

Comment: @Nuageux For `average`, use `np.add.reduceat` and then divide by lengths : `l`.

Comment: Yes, indeed... My brain should has stop functionning... Many thanks!

Comment: @Divakar I edit my question, since your solution doesn't work when the empty element is the last one. Any ideas?

Comment: @Divakar, First I'll like to thank you for everything. I have such crappy data, that it's still not working on everything (For example, the case where the empty element is the first one, i.e. `m[0]`). But I'll try to fix it

Comment: @Nuageux Nah, my bad really, didn't cover all grounds. The edits should settle it.

Comment: It's working! Many thanks and apologies for special cases :)

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) can be helpful for dealing with jagged arrays. Under the hood the solution below is like Divakars solution but with a little more overhead; however, if you systematically switch your datastructure in your code from a classical jagged array layout to this dense key-value array format, you can subsequently express pretty much any operation on this jagged array in a fully vectorized manner, which tends to rapidly pay off in terms of performance, readability, and numpythonicness in general.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
keys = np.concatenate([np.ones(len(row)*i for i, row in enumerate(m)])
values = np.concatenate(m)
unique_keys, minima_m = npi.group_by(keys).min(values)
# this doesnt have the -1 entry but if it is important to your data layout it is easy to map back:
result = -np.ones(len(m), dtype=minima_m.dtype)
result[unique_keys] = minima_m
```

Aside from the performance characteristics, there is also a memory implication; maintaining the keys array may seem wasteful; and it can be a little so if your rows are large. But if the size of the rows in your example is actually representative, there will actually be a memory saving in such a representation of your datastructure, since every additional numpy array that every row needs gobbles up about 100bytes or so as well.

Making the most of this requires some rethinking of how you work with jagged arrays across your application, because remapping between representations isnt particularly good for either readability or performance. So if you stick with one representation you never have to remap; but if you wanted to, going back to a jagged array is also super easy:

```
npi.group_by(keys).split(values)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll look into your package. On Github, there is an open issue about installation with Python 2.7, is it still unsolved? (I'm working with Python 2.7.6)

Comment: on pip you need to pip install pyyaml first; thats all, should work fine then.